# Tie 350ml liquor bottles to a string or chain?

Tags: clothing, comfort, efficiency

I'm dressing up for Halloween and my costume requires me to tie a couple of empty 350ml bottles to something I can wear around my neck. They have to be well secured.

The bottles look something like this:

[image: Small glass bottle]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might work is to tie the string or cord tightly around the bottle's neck, and then wrap adhesive tape around the neck, cord, and knot several times. You could use duct tape (since duct tape fixes everything!) or clear packing tape (so it wouldn't be visible).

Answer (score 0):

If tied properly, you will not need tape and extra knots.
I would use [constrictor knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrictor_knot) (and cut the string at the end if not thrown away with the bottles) in the [folding method, animated instructions here](http://www.animatedknots.com/constrictorfold/).

If you want to take the string off the bottles without using a knife, the clove hitch [(instructions on this site)](http://www.handymariner.com/clove-hitch/) would work well as long as the string stays tight when you have closed the knots.

Comment: I really like this solution. I've already done another method but this one looks interesting and secure as well.